# "..1" in the body of "[[.data.frame"

Tags: r, dataframe, ellipsis

When I look at the contents of `[[.data.frame` on my PC, this is what I get:

```
> get("[[.data.frame")
function (x, ..., exact = TRUE) 
{
    na <- nargs() - (!missing(exact))
    if (!all(names(sys.call()) %in% c("", "exact"))) 
        warning("named arguments other than 'exact' are discouraged")
    if (na < 3L) 
        (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) 
            as.matrix(x)[[i]]
        else .subset2(x, i, exact = exact))(x, ..., exact = exact)
    else {
        col <- .subset2(x, ..2, exact = exact)
        i <- if (is.character(..1)) 
            pmatch(..1, row.names(x), duplicates.ok = TRUE)
        else ..1
        .subset2(col, i, exact = exact)
    }
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

I've gotten used to `...`, but this is the first time I saw `..1` and `..2`. A quick search both in R help and Google returned mostly rubbish, since the dots are often interpreted as placeholders, so I'm hoping someone here can give me a pointer? Or am I missing something dreadfully obvious? Where do these come from and how can I use them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a way to reference the 1st, 2nd, ... elements of the special pairlist that is `...`. So `..1` is the way to refer to the first element of `...`, `..2` refers to the second element of `...` and so on.

This is mentioned in the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual in section [1.5.2 Dot-dot-dot arguments](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot-arguments), the relevant bit of which is:

> The value of `...` is a (special) pairlist whose elements are referred to by the special symbols `..1`, `..2`, ... which have the `DDVAL` bit set: when one of these is encountered it is looked up (via `ddfindVar`) in the value of the `...` symbol in the evaluation frame.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Gavin's answer:

They are also mentioned briefly in the help page for reserved words (`?Reserved`).

A really simple example of usage is

```
f <- function(...) print(..1)
f(x = 99)  #prints 99
f()        #throws an error
```